# Eclipse Configuration Error: Invalid Google App Engine directory

Tags: google-app-engine, directory

I have problem creating a Pydev Google App Engine project, the configuration stop at selecting the Google App Engine Directory.

Below is the error that i encountered after pointing the directory to C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine:

"Invalid Google App Engine directory. Did not find: C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django"

Please help!

Comment: I have same problem today on linux version of api. I didn't understand which directory structure the plugin is trying to access. Inside lib directory, there is a django directory name appended with django version.

Answer (score 4):

In 1.4.2 Google moved django into two folders: `django_0_96` and `django_1_2`.  You should copy one of those directories to just plain `django` (in the specified folder) to get it to work with the current PyDev.  Hopefully PyDev will update with a fix soon.

Comment: On Linux, you can create a link between these directories.

Comment: @apast Windows also allows this through the Junction tool http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Comment: From the paths in the question, it doesn't look like you're using linux, but to add to Jader's comment, to create the symlink in linux, execute "sudo ln -s django_0_96 django" from the GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE/lib directory