# Unresolved import in pydev

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I am a first time user of Python, I have Eclipse (Helios) on Windows XP and Pydev installed and all is well except that when I am following the [GAE tutorial for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html)

I get the unresolved import error on run_wsgi_app and webapp from 
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

The code runs fine. 
I have looked for an answer and added

`F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext` and

`F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp`

to be sure to my **PYTHONPATH** via the Eclipse Python Interpreter interface.
I have removed and re-added the interpreter, pressed Apply, restarted Eclipse but all to no avail.

I am posting this as I am sure many new users with **GAE + Python + Eclipse + Pydev** would have the same problem.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: In PyDev you should be able to create a Google App Engine project that will automatically find and add the required directories. If it isn't working correctly check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019469/eclipse-configuration-error-invalid-google-app-engine-directory/5022584#5022584

Comment: Yes thank you Calvin, creating a Google App Engine project (as opposed to a Python project) in Eclipse and following the Python GAE tutorial as before does indeed solve the original problem.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Add the package parent directory (the first directory with a **init**.py file)

```
F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine
```

to the PYTHONPATH in Eclipse under the 'External Libraries' tab.

Also beware of a bug in PyDev that does not respect/understand Python namespaces (as opposed to packages).  For more info see:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3284882&group_id=85796&atid=577329

Answer (score 0):

In general, add the package's parent directory to PYTHONPATH, not the module subdirectories:

```
F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine
```

Answer (score 0):

adding ${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/webapp2-2.5.2 to the "External Libraries" worked for me.
App Engine SDK ver:1.8.2
Python version: 2.7