# win32com DLL load failed

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, win32com

I'm trying to add win32com to Python 2.7. After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394887/unresolved-import-in-pydev?rq=1), I added the directory with the _init file (Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com) but I still get it. I went so far as to try to add a bunch of different folders to the path that seem to have to deal with win32com but I still get the error. If it knows where the file is and I added that folder to PYTHONPATH, why is this happening? I'm using PyDev with Eclipse Juno. My code:

```
import win32com.client

print("hello world")
```

when I try to run this, i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\EclipseWorkspace\PhotoScript\src\scriptLaunch.py", line 1, in     <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
   import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `classpath`? Are you sure you're not mixing up your Python and Java config?

Comment: sorry, I meant PYTHONPATH

Comment: Where are you getting this error? That doesn't look like a python exception to me.

Comment: Ok, update to reflects what's happening now. I was getting a red squiggle under the import line and but I have a difference problem now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython), it includes win32com:

> *The Python for Windows Extensions (PyWin32 version 214).
>           The interface to the Win32 API (win32api).
>           The interfaces to Win32 COM (win32com and win32comext).
>           The Pythonwin Development Environment.*

```
 *ActivePython is fully binary compatible with python.org Python builds to ensure that 3rd-party binary extensions just work*
```

Answer (score 4):

in my case typing in cmd:
**python C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install**
[cmd Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRoKX.png)

I hope this helps

Comment: YES!  Thank you!  Installing pypiwin32 and hit the error.  This helped a lot.  Go to your command prompt and type your version of the above code.  For me it was: "python C:\Users\First.M.Last\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install"

Answer (score 0):

Try to install python for windows extensions:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20210/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes/42285905#42285905) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)