# ImportError: No module named pywintypes

Tags: python, pywin32, keylogger, pyhook, pythoncom

I am working to make a small keylogger with Python, by using the pyHook, pythoncom and Pywin32 modules. Here is my code:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'C:\\important\\log.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent (event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10, chr(Event.Ascii))
    return True
hooks_manager=pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

When it runs, it returns this error message:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
ImportError: No module named pywintypes
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 26):

`pywintypes` is part of the [Python for Windows extensions](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html), otherwise known as pywin32. You'll need to install that to get access to `pywintypes`.

Note that as of this writing, `pywin32`'s maintainer doesn't upload files to PyPI, so you have to get an appropriate version of installer from http://pywin32.sf.net.

Comment: had to use `pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: @Elric be noted that as of this writing, there are only files for 3.6 for `pypiwin32`, so the command will only succeed for that particular version.

Comment: Same issue here. `pip install` says "Requirement already satisfied: pypinwin32 , and pywin32 >= 223." But yet, `import pywintypes` (which occurs when I `import pyttsx3`) says "no module named ..."

Comment: @Max the sam issue here.

Answer (score 23):

`pip install pypiwin32` worked for me

Answer (score 16):

For me it worked to copy the files (pythoncom38.dll and pywintypes38.dll)  from:

```
C:\Users\"Your user id"\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pywin32_system32
```

To the path:

```
C:\Users\"Your user id"\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\win32\lib
```

and

```
C:\Users\"Your user id"\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\win32
```

- After installation of Visual Studio, I need sometimes to restart computer after copy the files.

Comment: I just encountered this issue when installing a script that uses pyttsx3 on a freshly installed Windows 10 machine, and your solution worked perfectly. Why is this still a problem in November? Is it a problem with the pypiwin32 package? Has no one reported it as an issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know my answer is bit late but just run to this problem. Both pywin32 and pypiwin32 is installed on my virtualenv, my app is working fine during test. When I run pyinstaller to build my exe, this error showed up.

Solution:
I needed to install (through pip) pywin32 and pypiwin32 on my base python env ( not the virtualenv) for pyinstaller to build my exe.

Comment: How do you install in the base env? I have the same issue

Comment: just install pywin32 and pypiwin32 in your system ( global ), not just within a specific venv

Answer (score 2):

I typically `import pywintypes` or use a library that does.  This import suddenly stopped working following update to Windows 11.

Using PIP I uninstalled pywin32, then reinstalled it (into my global python as above). This worked, I can do the import now.  Just saying cause this is a simple step

Comment: I use IDLE to run the code and having this "No module named pywintypes" with Python 3.10 on Windows 11. Then I uninstall pywin32 using pip uninstall pywin32, then install it back: pip install pywin32, then I also closed IDLE and restart and open the py file and run it, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Just add pythoncom34.dll and pywintypes34.dll to your
C:\Python34\

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error when trying to create a python service using **pywin32** module.
I copied `pythoncom38.dll` and `pywintypes38.dll` into the root directory of the project and it solved the issue.