# Error finding module named pywintypes (Text-to-Speech in python using pyttsx3 on windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried every solution on Stackoverflow but my error doesn't seem to get solved . I have tried uninstalling and installing this package pyttsx3 also . Please help me . 
here is the error I am getting .

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py", line 20, in init

eng = _activeEngines[driverName]

File "C:\Python37\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in **getitem**
    o = self.datakey
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python37/tts2.py", line 2, in

engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py", line 22, in init

eng = Engine(driverName, debug)

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in **init**

self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in **init**

self._module = importlib.import_module(name)

File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import

File "", line 983, in _find_and_load

File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked

File "", line 728, in exec_module

File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in

import pythoncom

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in

import pywintypes

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'

My Code Is :

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
engine.say('Welcome ')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: pywintypes is a part of python for windows extensions. You need to install it to get access to it. Have you tried ```pip install pypiwin32```?

Comment: Yes tried several times . It gives message like this : - 
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (223)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (227)

Comment: Have you tried adding pythoncom34.dll and pywintypes34.dll to your C:\Python37\? Because as far as I remember, ```pip install pypiwin32``` works only for 3.6

Comment: No i haven't done that . How to do it ? From where can I get those files ?

Comment: They are dll files. A quick search for pythoncom37.dll should give you some results. You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes) which might be of some help. It helps solve the pywintypes error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issue like this last week. Its turns out to be I've had multiple version of python installed. Please try

`python3 -m pip install pywintypes`

see if is going to cure your problem.

Comment: No ! That is not solving the problem .

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't help there.

have you tried opening cmd, and typing import pywintypes?

What does it say when you do it?

Comment: You cannot import in cmd  , import wont be recognised as a command.

Comment: I guess what @Sorunlu meant is to open python in cmd and then try importing it.

Comment: Try opening in cmd, and try importing as a module if it doesn't load it up it means you've got multi able of python installed

Comment: Okay let me try this .

Comment: I had python 2.7 installed along with python 3.7 . I uninstalled python 2.7 and the error has gone.  Dont know what might have been the problem keeping both .

Comment: I am glad you sorted your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing pywin32 with this command:

```
pip install pywin32
```

If that does not work than follow steps given:

Step - 1- Install pywin32 with this command:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Step - 2 - Import win32api just like this:

```
from win32api import *
```