# Python not installed at C:\Python but at ProgramFiles microsoft visual studio

Tags: python

At Windows 10, I just installed python but could not found it at `c:\python` but

```
program files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64
```

my machine does not have an internet connection, is that the cause?

I try to run python myscript.py but hitting error like `olefile module not found`

I manually download and install and works), now the error is pywintypes module not found?

is this due to installation?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes

Comment: yes but my machine does not has internet connection, i manually download package and install it. any solution to make pip install command works without internet?

Comment: tried this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725843/installing-python-packages-without-internet-and-using-source-code-as-tar-gz-and

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I install as admin.
Then select custom install, install for everyone.