# ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes38.dll)

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, pywin32, pyttsx

I was making a python friend using pyttsx3, but I see the following error

```
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes38.dll)
```

Am using windows and python 3.Any help s quick as possible

**the code is here**

```
import pyttsx3
friend = pyttsx3.init()
speech = input ("Say Something: ")
friend.say(speech)
friend.runAndWait()
```

**error in vscterminal **

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Clive-main>C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/user/Desktop/Clive-main/Clive-main/friend.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/Clive-main/Clive-main/friend.py", line 2, in <module>
    friend = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 136, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 110, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes38.dll)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named pywintypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes)

Answer (score 4):

Just copy the 'pythoncom39.dll' and 'pywintypes39.dll' from this path (usually these files are located here)

```
C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pywin32_system32
```

to:

```
C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib
```

It worked for me. I hope this has been helpful.