# python, pyside6, and moviepy issue invalid or missing encoding declaration pywintypes38.dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy, pyside6

### description

hello guys I have a python project with the following import statement the project used to work just fine but after sometime

the following line of code
`from moviepy.editor import concatenate_videoclips,  VideoFileClip`
causes below error, when this line is commented the error disappears and everything just continues to work but I need to import those to for my application to do it's job but when this is present the error appears and the application halts.

### error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\tokenize.py", line 330, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\gui1.0.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gui.infoarea import InfoArea
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\gui\infoarea\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gui.services import FileProcessingService
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\gui\services\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from safe2watch.pipeline import run_pipeline
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\safe2watch\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .pipeline import run_pipeline
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\safe2watch\pipeline\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import concatenate_videoclips #,  VideoFileClip
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip import AudioFileClip
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from moviepy.audio.AudioClip import AudioClip
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 7, in <module>
    from moviepy.audio.io.ffmpeg_audiowriter import ffmpeg_audiowrite
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 7, in <module>
    from moviepy.config import get_setting
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\moviepy\config.py", line 35, in <module>
    from imageio.plugins.ffmpeg import get_exe
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\ffmpeg.py", line 136, in <module>
    import imageio_ffmpeg
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._utils import get_ffmpeg_exe, get_ffmpeg_version
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\imageio_ffmpeg\_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import resource_filename
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import appdirs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556, in module_from_spec
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 52, in create_module
    return self.load_module(spec.name)
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 37, in load_module
    __import__(extant)
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 560, in <module>
    import win32com.shell
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "D:\Learning\practical applications\safe2watch\env\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "shibokensupport/signature/loader.py", line 61, in feature_imported
  File "shibokensupport/feature.py", line 137, in feature_imported
  File "shibokensupport/feature.py", line 148, in _mod_uses_pyside
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\inspect.py", line 997, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\inspect.py", line 979, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\inspect.py", line 794, in findsource
    lines = linecache.getlines(file, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\linecache.py", line 136, in updatecache
    with tokenize.open(fullname) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\tokenize.py", line 394, in open
    encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\tokenize.py", line 371, in detect_encoding
    encoding = find_cookie(first)
  File "C:\Users\mohamed\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\lib\tokenize.py", line 335, in find_cookie
    raise SyntaxError(msg)
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'D:\\Learning\\practical applications\\safe2watch\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32\\pywintypes38.dll'
```

I have the following requirements file, and I have these requirements installed in a python virtual environment.

```
altgraph==0.17.3
asttokens==2.0.8
autopep8==1.7.0
backcall==0.2.0
certifi==2022.9.24
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
colorama==0.4.6
coloredlogs==15.0.1
contourpy==1.0.5
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.3
decorator==4.4.2
docopt==0.6.2
entrypoints==0.4
executing==1.1.1
ffmpeg==1.4
flake8==6.0.0
flatbuffers==22.9.24
fonttools==4.37.4
future==0.18.3
greenlet==2.0.2
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.4
imageio==2.22.1
imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.7
ipykernel==6.16.0
ipython==8.5.0
iso8601==1.1.0
jedi==0.18.1
jupyter-client==7.3.5
jupyter-core==4.11.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.6.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mccabe==0.7.0
moviepy==1.0.3
mpmath==1.2.1
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
networkx==2.8.7
numpy==1.23.3
onnxruntime==1.12.1
opencv-python==4.6.0.66
opencv-python-headless==4.6.0.66
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pefile==2022.5.30
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.2.0
proglog==0.1.10
progressbar2==4.0.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.31
protobuf==4.21.7
psutil==5.9.2
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycodestyle==2.10.0
pydload==1.0.9
pyflakes==3.0.1
Pygments==2.13.0
pyinstaller==5.7.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.14
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyreadline3==3.4.1
PySide6==6.4.2
PySide6-Addons==6.4.2
PySide6-Essentials==6.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-utils==3.3.3
pytz==2022.4
PyWavelets==1.4.1
pywin32==305
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
pyzmq==24.0.1
requests==2.28.1
scikit-image==0.19.3
scipy==1.9.2
shiboken6==6.4.2
simplejson==3.18.3
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.4
stack-data==0.5.1
sympy==1.11.1
tifffile==2022.8.12
toml==0.10.2
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.64.1
traitlets==5.4.0
typing-extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.12
uuid==1.30
wcwidth==0.2.5
WebOb==1.8.7
Werkzeug==2.2.3
```

Comment: "when this line is commented the error disappears and everything just works fine". If that is indeed the case, then remove that line. Not sure what you are asking here if you already found the solution?

Comment: @Wayne the problem is that I need this line to be able to use these functions

Comment: Then I'd advise you to edit your post. Everything isn't working just 'fine'. To others reading your post, it seems like you were just wondering about what was going on but were fine now. About that issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66923423/8508004) and translate it to `pywintypes38` instead of `39`, [here](https://github.com/fkie-cad/RoAMer/issues/5#issue-678988719) or [here](https://github.com/KBNLresearch/iromlab/issues/100#issuecomment-594656069).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by removing the virtual environment folder and reinstalling all the requirements again.

Comment: Thanks for following up & posting what got you past this. Hopefully it will help someone else.