# No module named 'pywintypes'

Tags: python, pywin32, python-3.9

so as the title says, I can't import pywintypes.
I read through all the existing questions but failed to find a solution that works.

Here's my setup:

```
Python install: C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39
Pip install directory: P:/pip
```

I guess the issue is that pip installs in the 'wrong directory' but here's what I tried so far:
Copy both dlls from P:/pip/pywin32_system32 to:

- Python Directory/Lib
- Python Directory/Lib/site-packages
- Python Directory/Lib/site-packages/pywin32_system32
- Python Directory/Lib/site-packages/win32
- Python Directory/Lib/site-packages/win32/lib
- Python Directory/DLLs

```
pip install pywin32 & 
pip install pypiwin32
```

I'm trying to initialize pyttsx3.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes