# No Module named pywintypes but installed both pywin32 and pypiwin32

Tags: pytorch, package

When trying to load a model via torch.load, I get the following error message. I've followed [this guide](https://helloshreyas.in/how-to-install-detectron2-on-windows-machine) to install to setup my environment.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 model = torch.load(f'../models/20231112_0611.pth')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1014, in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, weights_only, mmap, **pickle_load_args)
   1012             except RuntimeError as e:
   1013                 raise pickle.UnpicklingError(UNSAFE_MESSAGE + str(e)) from None
-> 1014         return _load(opened_zipfile,
   1015                      map_location,
   1016                      pickle_module,
   1017                      overall_storage=overall_storage,
   1018                      **pickle_load_args)
   1019 if mmap:
   1020     raise RuntimeError("mmap can only be used with files saved with ",
   1021                        "`torch.save(_use_new_zipfile_serialization=True), "
   1022                        "please torch.save your checkpoint with this option in order to use mmap.")

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1422, in _load(zip_file, map_location, pickle_module, pickle_file, overall_storage, **pickle_load_args)
   1420 unpickler = UnpicklerWrapper(data_file, **pickle_load_args)
   1421 unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
-> 1422 result = unpickler.load()
   1424 torch._utils._validate_loaded_sparse_tensors()
   1425 torch._C._log_api_usage_metadata(
   1426     "torch.load.metadata", {"serialization_id": zip_file.serialization_id()}
   1427 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1415, in _load.<locals>.UnpicklerWrapper.find_class(self, mod_name, name)
   1413         pass
   1414 mod_name = load_module_mapping.get(mod_name, mod_name)
-> 1415 return super().find_class(mod_name, name)

File c:\users\andrew\documents\code\repos\detectron2\detectron2\modeling\__init__.py:2
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
----> 2 from detectron2.layers import ShapeSpec
      4 from .anchor_generator import build_anchor_generator, ANCHOR_GENERATOR_REGISTRY
      5 from .backbone import (
      6     BACKBONE_REGISTRY,
      7     FPN,
   (...)
     18     SwinTransformer,
     19 )

File c:\users\andrew\documents\code\repos\detectron2\detectron2\layers\__init__.py:2
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
----> 2 from .batch_norm import FrozenBatchNorm2d, get_norm, NaiveSyncBatchNorm, CycleBatchNormList
      3 from .deform_conv import DeformConv, ModulatedDeformConv
      4 from .mask_ops import paste_masks_in_image

File c:\users\andrew\documents\code\repos\detectron2\detectron2\layers\batch_norm.py:4
      2 import torch
      3 import torch.distributed as dist
----> 4 from fvcore.nn.distributed import differentiable_all_reduce
      5 from torch import nn
      6 from torch.nn import functional as F

File <frozen zipimport>:259, in load_module(self, fullname)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\fvcore-0.1.5.post20221221-py3.9.egg\fvcore\nn\__init__.py:2
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
----> 2 from .activation_count import activation_count, ActivationCountAnalysis
      3 from .flop_count import flop_count, FlopCountAnalysis
      4 from .focal_loss import (
      5     sigmoid_focal_loss,
      6     sigmoid_focal_loss_jit,
      7     sigmoid_focal_loss_star,
      8     sigmoid_focal_loss_star_jit,
      9 )

File <frozen zipimport>:259, in load_module(self, fullname)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\fvcore-0.1.5.post20221221-py3.9.egg\fvcore\nn\activation_count.py:10
      7 import torch.nn as nn
      8 from torch import Tensor
---> 10 from .jit_analysis import JitModelAnalysis
     11 from .jit_handles import generic_activation_jit, Handle
     14 # A dictionary that maps supported operations to their activation count handles.

File <frozen zipimport>:259, in load_module(self, fullname)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\fvcore-0.1.5.post20221221-py3.9.egg\fvcore\nn\jit_analysis.py:16
     14 import torch
     15 import torch.nn as nn
---> 16 from fvcore.common.checkpoint import _named_modules_with_dup
     17 from torch import Tensor
     18 from torch.jit import _get_trace_graph, TracerWarning

File <frozen zipimport>:259, in load_module(self, fullname)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\fvcore-0.1.5.post20221221-py3.9.egg\fvcore\common\checkpoint.py:12
     10 import torch
     11 import torch.nn as nn
---> 12 from iopath.common.file_io import HTTPURLHandler, PathManager
     13 from termcolor import colored
     14 from torch.nn.parallel import DataParallel, DistributedDataParallel

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\iopath-0.1.9-py3.9.egg\iopath\__init__.py:3
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
----> 3 from iopath.common import LazyPath, PathManager, file_lock, get_cache_dir
      4 from iopath.tabular.tabular_io import TabularPathHandler, TabularUriParser
      6 from .version import __version__

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\iopath-0.1.9-py3.9.egg\iopath\common\__init__.py:3
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
----> 3 from iopath.common.file_io import LazyPath, PathManager, file_lock, get_cache_dir
      6 __all__ = [
      7     "LazyPath",
      8     "PathManager",
      9     "get_cache_dir",
     10     "file_lock",
     11 ]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\iopath-0.1.9-py3.9.egg\iopath\common\file_io.py:27
     13 from typing import (
     14     IO,
     15     Any,
   (...)
     23     Union,
     24 )
     25 from urllib.parse import urlparse
---> 27 import portalocker  # type: ignore
     28 from iopath.common.download import download
     29 from iopath.common.event_logger import VTYPE, EventLogger

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\portalocker-2.8.2-py3.9.egg\portalocker\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from . import __about__, constants, exceptions, portalocker, utils
      3 try:  # pragma: no cover
      4     from .redis import RedisLock

File ~\anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\portalocker-2.8.2-py3.9.egg\portalocker\portalocker.py:15
     12 if os.name == 'nt':  # pragma: no cover
     13     import msvcrt
---> 15     import pywintypes
     16     import win32con
     17     import win32file

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'
```

I've tried installing/reinstalling pywin32.pypiwin32. I've tried moving pythoncom39.dll and pywintypes39.dll but unsure where to move them exactly too since the [only other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes) seems to do it not in a virtual environment.

How do I get this to run locally?