# pyttsx3 don't function when i run my code

Tags: python, pyttsx3

when i tried to run my code it gives me some big error like import pywintypes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes' and KeyError: None but i dont understand why

this is my code

```
import pyttsx3 


engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.say("ciao")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named pywintypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes)